# npm install and deprecated warnings

Tags: node.js, npm

I've started to use npm recently and sometimes during installations some warnings pop up.

For example, running

```
 npm install gulp-chimp --save-dev
```

yields the following warnings

> npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
>
> npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
>
> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130

My question is not specific to gulp-chimp but to npm in general. Should I try to update these packages or not? I understand it's the developer's call to use the updated package or not and I feel like I may break something by trying to update the packages myself but I'm also anxious about letting vulnerabilities be.

Comment: Before any update, you must be sure of the impacts of them into your project / tools. 

If you like updates, you should be ready to reconfigure every single tool of your development environment as many times as needed.Keep a version script or a list to track your Dev tools and their versions.
This way you have a "fallback", in case a update breaks anything.

Comment: @AndreCanilho has a good point. Are you using GIT? This might ease your anxiety a bit and feel better about making major changes to your core dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ensure that updating the dependencies doesn't break anything, version control is a must. Often you can update the deprecated dependencies without much trouble, but there are definitely times where doing so will cause breakage in the package using it.

What I don't recommend doing is ignoring the deprecation errors. While it's true that the package maintainer needs to update it on their end, the problem is still very much yours. Many of these outdated packages have known security vulnerabilities that are now going to be impacting your application.

To get a solid picture of which dependencies are outdated, run something like:

`npm outdated -depth=3`

It defaults to a depth of `0` which will only check top-level dependencies, so increasing the depth level to some extent (3 is just an example) will reveal many more dependencies that are out of date.

The more important thing, as you already noted, is finding out which of these dependencies may have known vulnerabilities. You can test for these vulnerabilities using a tool like [Snyk](https://snyk.io/), which checks your dependencies against an [open-source database of vulnerabilities](https://snyk.io/vuln). Snyk will let you patch your vulnerabilities (using either a CLI or automated Github pull requests) without upgrading, in the case that those upgrades break your code.

*Full disclosure: I work at Snyk. :) That being said this is exactly the problem it's meant to help with.*